# javascript/regex to ignore semicolons in double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I've been stumped for bit on this one - I have a string that is almost a semicolon delimited string it would be something like this:

> one; two; three "four; five;six"; seven

I'd like to split this up using a regex in javascript into an array like this (e.g. ignoring any semicolons inside double quotes):

> ['one','two','three "four; five;six"','seven']

I've tried adapting known working CSV functions, but they seem to be able to be adapted to work with the third element ('three "four;five;six";').

It seems like a regex type of problem, but if a solution exists using more than regex, I'm certainly interested!

**update**: I should also note that there may be spaces before or after the semicolons in the quoted string. I've updated the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't allow for escaped quotes inside your quotes (e.g. `"this has \"escaped quotes\" inside"`) then this should work:

```
var rx = /(?!;|$)[^;"]*(("[^"]*")[^;"]*)*/g;
var str = 'one; two; three "four;five;six"; seven';
var res = str.match(rx)
// res = ['one', ' two', ' three "four;five;six"', ' seven']
```

Note that you need the [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!;|$)` at the beginning of the regex to keep it from matching the empty string, otherwise the `match` method matches empty strings in front of each of the semicolons for some reason.

***Update:***

I think this regular expression should work with escaped quotes as well (although I'd appreciate feedback on the correctness). I've also added the extra `\s` in the negative-lookahead pattern to strip off whitespace after the preceding semicolon.

```
/(?!\s|;|$)[^;"]*("(\\.|[^\\"])*"[^;"]*)*/g
```

Comment: This is great! How could I get this to work with both ' and "?
var str = 'one; two; three "four;five;six"; seven';
var str2 = "one; two; three 'four;five;six'; seven";

Comment: @marknadal - It looks like you want to make this also work for single-quoted strings. In that case, try this: [`(?!\s|;|$)(?:[^;"']*(?:"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"|'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*')?)*`](http://www.rexfiddle.net/08JT1bK)

Comment: Worked flawlessly, one of the most impressive regex I've seen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This strips spaces before and after semicolons:

```
'one; two; three "four;five;six"; seven'.match(/(?!;| |$)([^";]*"[^"]*")*([^";]*[^ ";])?/g)

['one', 'two', 'three";four;five;six"', 'seven']

'one ; two"; three ; "four" ; five ; "six ; seven'.match(/(?!;| |$)([^";]*"[^"]*")*([^";]*[^ ";])?/g)

['one', 'two" ; three ; "four" ; five ; "six', 'seven']
```

It doesn't try to deal with escaped quotes though.