# javascript - new regex after regex used

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text

```
TABLES:
  TABLE1: COLUMN1;
  TABLE2: COLUMN_A;
  TABLE3(TABLE1, TABLE2): COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2;
ENDTABLES
```

First of all, I wanted to get what is between `TABLES - ENDTABLES` and I did this:

```
var text = "all of the above";
var tablesRegex = /TABLES\:([\s\S]*?)ENDTABLES/;
alert(tablesRegex.exec(text)[1]);
```

But then I wanted to get this in an array:

```
["TABLE1: COLUMN1","TABLE2: COLUMN_A","TABLE3(TABLE1, TABLE2): COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2"]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12335449/1132749), but frankly I didn't understand it.

Any help with how to obtain that array?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

While I can split the match string by using:

```
tablesRegex.exec(text)[1].split(";");
```

I'm actually looking for a regex solution (**If possible**)

**UPDATE 2**

a new regexp... other than `/TABLES\:([\s\S]*?)ENDTABLES/`, in order to obtain what is inside those strings without the semicolons

Comment: `.split()` can take a `RegExp`.

Answer (score 1):

You state you're looking for a regex solution ...

```
var results = str.match(/\bTABLE\d[^;]+/g)
console.log(results)
```

```js
var str = '\
TABLES: \
  TABLE1: COLUMN1; \
  TABLE2: COLUMN_A; \
  TABLE3(TABLE1, TABLE2): COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2; \
ENDTABLES';

var results = str.match(/\bTABLE\d[^;]+/g)

document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = 
   '<ul><li>' + 
    results.join('</li><li>') + 
    '</li></ul>';
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just split the text using `;`

```
var tablesRegex = /TABLES\:([\s\S]*?)ENDTABLES/;
var x = tablesRegex.exec(text)[1];

var array = x.split(/\s*;\s*/)
```

Comment: well yeah...but I was actually looking for a regex solution :) (I'll update my question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function splitWeirdTables(str){
  return str.replace(/^TABLES\:(.+)ENDTABELS$/, '$1').split(/;/);
}
console.log(splitWeirdTables(yourStringHere));
```

Comment: Does this function not provide the results you seek?