# Split a string by ; as long as it's not between » «

Tags: javascript, split

Even though the title is self-explanatory, I'll describe the problem a bit.

So I want to split a string by `;`. However, if the `;` is between these two characters `» «` then don't split it. Of course, there can be many `» «` in one string.

This: `var myString = "Split this; »Don't split this; don't split«; split this again; this is split";`

Should return this: `["Split this", "»Don't split this; don't split«", "split this again", "this is split"]`

I assume this could be solved with regex, but I had no luck yet.

Here's the code to get us started: http://jsbin.com/wivuyucifo/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 1):

I would mark this as a duplicate since I just lifted the following regex code from another StackOverflow answer (see: [javascript/regex to ignore semicolons in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335355/javascript-regex-to-ignore-semicolons-in-double-quotes)), however, the following answer should help explain how to translate that answer to one that has differing start/end quotes.

```js
var myString = "Split this; »Don't split this; don't split«; split this again; this is split";

var regex = /(?!;|$)[^;»]*((»[^«]*«)[^;»]*)*/g;
var results = myString.match(regex);

document.write(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Comment: I've found a "bug" in the code - not sure if it's a bug though. However, in this example, there is only one `;` yet the solution returns array of 3 items: http://jsbin.com/meqohekoto/1/edit

Comment: @uglycode Thanks for pointing that out. I mistakenly had a `«` at the end, when it needed a `»`. I updated the answer to reflect the changes. LMK if that works out for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to worry about nested *guillemets*, you can use a pretty simple algorithim like this:

```js
var myString = "Split this; »Don't split this; don't split«; split this again; this is split";

console.log(mySplit(myString));

function mySplit(input) {
  let result = [];
  let isQuoted = false;
  let temp = "";
  
  for(let i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let c = input[i];
    switch (c) {
      case "»":
        temp += c;
        isQuoted = true;
        break;
      case "«":
        temp += c;
        isQuoted = false;
        break;
      case ";":
        if (isQuoted) {
          temp += c;
        } else {
          result.push(temp);
          temp = "";
        }
        break;
      default:
        temp += c;
        break;
    }
  }
  result.push(temp);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to `result.push(temp);` one more time before the return (after the loop) to get the last match.

Comment: @Quantastical yup, thanks. Updated. Your regex solution is probably better in most cases though.